# Extend laravel login validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5, authentication, extra

How would I extend the laravel login with extra validation rules. I would like to check if user has role on successfull login, if there is no role attached to user I want to deny the login process.

I see that in LoginController I can override the login method

```
public function login(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    //dd($this->validateLogin($request));
    parent::login($request);
}
```

but I have no idea how do I get back the user object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the user must authenticate itself and THEN you want to check the role. It is not required to have a specific role. If so, you can override the authenticated() method on your LoginController like this: ( You have to write **use Illuminate\Http\Request;** on top of the File.

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(empty($user->role)) {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        return back()->withErrors(['There is no role specified']);
    }
}
```

If you want the user to have s specific role you can override the credentials() method in the LoginController:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['role'] = 'requiredRole';
    return $credentials;
}
```